# Meaning of shown methods

Tags: c++, methods, process, command-line-arguments

in one constructor that I am **analysing** are the methods below:

```
if (validParOptions.found(optionName))
{
parRunControl_.runPar(argc, argv); 
break;  //leave loop
}
```

**with**

```
ParRunControl parRunControl_ //- Switch on/off parallel mode.
```

**and**

```
void runPar(int& argc, char**& argv)
{
RunPar = true;  //bool RunPar;
if (!Pstream::init(argc, argv))
{
Info<< "Failed to start parallel run" << endl;
Pstream::exit(1);
}
}
```

**and herein**

```
bool Foam::UPstream::init(int& argc, char**& argv) //Spawns slave processes and                      
{                                                  //initialises inter-communication                                                                                  
FatalErrorIn("UPstream::init(int& argc, char**& argv)")
{                                                                                                                       
<< "Trying to use the dummy Pstream library." << nl                                                                                                                             
<< "This dummy library cannot be used in parallel mode"                                                                                                                               
<< Foam::exit(FatalError);                                                                                                                               
return false;                                                                                                                               
}
```

Within the first if condition the existance of options of commandlinearguments are checked and like the description of the last method `init` tells a slave process should be spawned
und inter-communication should be initialised. Two quesitons:

1. I don't see where in method `init` a process is spawned. Rather I only see a
   error message within the method. Am I missing something?
2. Do Options in commandlinearguments generally spawn slave process?

greetings streight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a macro because [it seems to have lots of different invocations](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.x/search?p=1&q=FatalErrorIn&type=Code). However, the error message is staring you right in the face: it won't let you use that code.
Take a look at the other source files:

https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.x/blob/95dc52c102041058f0bcfc8b6aab6b41b20dc313/src/Pstream/dummy/UPstream.C

https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.x/blob/95dc52c102041058f0bcfc8b6aab6b41b20dc313/src/Pstream/dummy/UOPwrite.C

https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.x/blob/95dc52c102041058f0bcfc8b6aab6b41b20dc313/src/Pstream/dummy/UIPread.C

They either have empty definitions or contain `notImplemented`. The big hint is that they all lie in the `dummy` directory.

My guess is you're probably pulling from the wrong headers. Take a look at this:

https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.x/blob/master/src/Pstream/mpi/UPstream.C

It actually has code:

```
bool Foam::UPstream::init(int& argc, char**& argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int numprocs;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myProcNo_);

    /* SNIP */

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have a few questions about this. 1. If I go to the class reference of class PStream I only find the method that I have posted. Why? Is there a mistake in the library? 2.What is a dummy directory for?

Comment: @Streight All I can think of is "mock" ups which are used for unit testing. As to why you only have the "dummy" version, I have no idea. Consider downloading the version from github if you need to.

Comment: I'm just analysing a source code, so I don't have to download the other version. However I have to be sure which is the right version included in the code I'm analysing. In the OpenFOAM library for init() only the version I included is shown, but when looking up the .C files of class UpStream on my PC I get three different files with three different init() methods. How am I suppossed to know which one will be used in the code I am analysing?

Comment: @Streight I don't know. Try looking at the makefiles.